# Laravel - Dynamic input form duplicates record during update

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create Dynamic input form array using Laravel-5.8

[image: leave request]

I have these two models:

```
class HrLeaveType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_types';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'company_id',
                  'leave_type_name',
                  'no_of_days',
                  'leave_type_code',
              ];    
}

class HrLeaveTypeDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_type_details';
    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'leave_type_id',
                  'company_id',
                  'employment_type_code',
                  'no_of_days',
              ];

    public function leavetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveType', 'leave_type_id', 'id');
    }

    public function employmenttype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmploymentType', 'employment_type_code', 'employment_type_code' );
    }    
}
```

Request Rules:

```
class UpdateLeaveTypeRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    { 
            'leave_type_name' => 
            [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('hr_leave_types')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query
                    ->where('leave_type_name', 1)
                    ->where('company_id', 1);
            })->ignore($this->leave_type) 
            ],            

            'leave_type_code' => [
                 'nullable', 
                 'string',
                 'max:10',              
            ],                     

            'no_of_days'           => 'required|array',
            'no_of_days.*' => [
                 'required', 
                 'numeric',
                 'max:120'               
            ],                                         
            'employment_type_code'           => 'required|array', 
            'employment_type_code.*' => [
                 'required',                 
            ],                     

        ];
    }     
}
```

And then the Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $leavetype              =           HrLeaveType::findOrFail($id);
    $employmenttypes        =           HrEmploymentType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
    $leavetypedetails       =           HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->get();
    return view('leave.leave_types.edit')
            ->with('leavetype', $leavetype)
            ->with('leavetypedetails', $leavetypedetails)        
            ->with('employmenttypes', $employmenttypes);
}

public function update(UpdateLeaveTypeRequest $request, $id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {

    $leavetype = HrLeaveType::findOrFail($id);
        $leavetype = new HrLeaveType();
        $leavetype->leave_type_name             = $request->leave_type_name;
        $leavetype->leave_type_code             = $request->leave_type_code;
        $leavetype->description                 = $request->description;

        $leavetype->save();                         

        HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->delete();

       foreach ( $request->employment_type_code as $key => $employment_type_code){

            $leavetypedetail = new HrLeaveTypeDetail();
            $leavetypedetail->no_of_days                    = $request->no_of_days[$key];
            $leavetypedetail->employment_type_code          = $request->employment_type_code[$key];               
            $leavetypedetail->leave_type_id                 = $leavetype->id;               
            $leavetypedetail->save();
         }

         DB::commit();

            Session::flash('success', 'Leave Type is updated successfully');
            return redirect()->route('leave.leave_types.index');
    } 
    catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
        DB::rollback();
        $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
        if($errorCode == 1062){
            Session::flash('error', 'Duplicate Entry! Please try again');
        }
        return back();
    }         
    catch (Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollback();

            Session::flash('error', 'Leave Type update failed!');
            return redirect()->route('leave.leave_types.index');
    }
}
```

view blade

```
    <form  action="{{route('leave.leave_types.update', ['id'=>$leavetype->id])}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">


       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">  

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Leave Type Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="leave_type_name" placeholder="Enter leave type name here" class="form-control" value="{{old('leave_type_name',$leavetype->leave_type_name)}}">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Leave Type Code:</label>
              <input  type="text" name="leave_type_code" placeholder="Enter leave type code here" class="form-control" value="{{old('leave_type_code',$leavetype->leave_type_code)}}">
            </div>
          </div>               


          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description here ..." value="{{old('description',$leavetype->description)}}">{{old('description',$leavetype->description)}}</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

   <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Employment Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">Leave Days<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col"><a class="btn btn-info addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($leavetypedetails as $leavetypedetail)
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%">                    
                                <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Employment Type" tabindex="1" name="employment_type_code[]">

                                        <option name="employment_type_code[]" value="{{$leavetypedetail->employmenttype->employment_type_code}}">{{$leavetypedetail->employmenttype->employment_type_name}}</option>
                                        @foreach($employmenttypes as $employmenttype)
                                            <option name="employment_type_code[]" value="{{$employmenttype->employment_type_code}}">{{$employmenttype->employment_type_name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach                                        
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="35%"><input value="{{$leavetypedetail->no_of_days}}" type="text" name="no_of_days[]" class="form-control" max="120"></td>
                            <td width="5%"><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
                         @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.update') }}</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('leave.leave_types.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>           

    </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addRow').on('click', function () {
            addRow();

        });
        function addRow() {
            var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
'                                <td width="60%"><select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Employment Type" tabindex="1" name="employment_type_code[]">\n' +
                       '             <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Employment Type</option>\n' +
                       '              @if($employmenttypes->count() > 0 )\n' +
                       '                 @foreach($employmenttypes as $employmenttype)\n' +
                       '                 <option value="{{$employmenttype->employment_type_code}}">{{$employmenttype->employment_type_name}}</option>\n' +
                       '                 @endforeach\n' +
                       '             @endif\n' +
                       '         </select></td>\n' +
'                                <td width="35%"><input type="number" name="no_of_days[]" placeholder="Enter leave days here" class="form-control no_of_days" max="120"></td>\n' +
'                                <td width="5%"><a   class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>\n' +
'                             </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(addRow);
            addRemoveListener();
        };
    addRemoveListener();
});
```

When I submitted the form for update,

1. I observed that the application save another data (duplicated) the model HrLeaveType into the database.
2. It replace the value of  employment_type_code in the HrLeaveTypeDetail model with the latest row in HrLeaveType.

Why am I having these issues and how do I resolve it?

Thanks